# How to pre-populate fields on click of a button in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks

I am trying to pre-populate the form fields, that are replicated, from the fields that are already filled. On clicking the "Add fields" button, the fields are getting replicated. But I want them to get pre-populated using the data filled in the already existing fields.

From where can I get hold of the input values?

````
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([{ name: '', age: '' }]);

  const addFields = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let newField = { name: "", age: '' };
    setInputFields([...inputFields, newField]);
  };

  const handleFormChange = (index, e) => {
    let data=[...inputFields];
    data[index][e.target.name]=[e.target.value];
    setInputFields(data);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {inputFields.map((input, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter name"
                value={input.name}
                onChange={(e)=>handleFormChange(index, e)}
              />
              <input
                type="number"
                name="age"
                placeholder="Enter Age"
                value={input.age}
                onChange={(e)=>handleFormChange(index, e)}
              />
              <br />
              <br />
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button onClick={addFields}>Add Field</button>
        <br />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to track changes in `input` with an `onChange` handler.

Also, you are not setting values from the last input fields anywhere to be able to duplicate them. The below code might work as you expect:

```js
const { useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([{ name: '', age: '' }]);

  const addFields = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const temp = inputFields.slice()
    , length = temp.length - 1
    , { name, age } = temp[length]
    
    // Set value from last input into the new field
    let newField = { name, age }
    setInputFields([...temp, newField])
  }
  , handleChange = (index, event) => {
    const temp = inputFields.slice() // Make a copy of the input array first.
    inputFields[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value // Update it with the modified values.
    setInputFields(temp) // Update the state.
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {inputFields.map((input, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index}>
              <input
                onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)}
                value={input.name}
                type="text"
                name="name"
                placeholder="Enter name"
              />
              <input
                onChange={e => handleChange(index, e)}
                value={input.age}
                type="number"
                name="age"
                placeholder="Enter Age"
              />
              <br />
              <br />
            </div>
          );
        })}
        <button onClick={addFields}>Add Field</button>
        <br />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks! But I didn't understand what's the difference if I do not use the temp array made by shallow copy using slice() method and instead use the inputFields array only?

Comment: @curious_Coder This answer might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js

Comment: @curious_Coder Also, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755997/why-cant-i-directly-modify-a-components-state-really

Comment: But I am not using arr.push for adding new array elements. I am using spread operator only, as suggested in the answers.

Comment: I am sorry, I think I was not able to make my question clear. My question was why to create this temp array- 
const temp = inputFields.slice()
    , length = temp.length - 1
    , { name, age } = temp[length]

I used-
const { name, age } = inputFields[inputFields.length - 1];

      let newField = { name, age };
      setInputFields([...inputFields, newField]);

....and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `value` property on the input field to populate, e.g:

```
<input
  value={input.name}
  type="text"
  name="name"
  placeholder="Enter name"
/>
```

Comment: I have actually done that but the values are not updated in the replicated fields. I will update the code.